# Business Application with Grok and ZODB

Tags: zodb, grok

*DISCLAIMER:  I'm new to Grok.*

I've been thinking about writing a business application (like accounting/sales/payroll) with Grok and ZODB.
As you know, a business application

1. does a lot of INSERT.
2. does a lot of SELECT on usually large sets of data.
3. runs ad-hoc queries (a.k.a reports) on the data.

Now I was wondering if these requirements can be satisfied with ZODB.  I'm sure (1) is a piece of cake but I have absolutely no idea about (2) and (3).

What do you folks, experienced with ZODB (and Grok), think about this?  I'd really appreciate any hint/idea.

TIA,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this post (http://www.coactivate.org/projects/topp-engineering/blog/2009/03/20/to-zodb-or-not-to-zodb) the author presents two characteristics (disadvantages?) of ZODB:

- No ad-hoc queries.
- Migrations are inconvenient and expensive.

ZODB is very interesting but, IMHO, the major drawback is that the data is dependent of original code.

Grok is a good framework, but maybe you can look Pyramid (www.pylonsproject.org), that has also support for traversal and ZODB, with the advantage of a more numerous community.

Comment: After some research, I gave up the idea of writing a business application with ZODB or Grok for the reasons you mentioned. Thanks for the pointer.